# Langchain parsing list of lists without using eval()?

Tags: python, langchain

How would I use a langchain parser to parse a list of lists? Example below:

“[[test, positive], [text2, negative]]”

I don’t want to use eval() or ast.literal_eval() since occasionally there can be characters in the list elements that force an error. Thank you!

I tried using eval(), ast.literal_eval(), and the comma parser from langchain

Comment: What do you mean by parse? What do you expect to be the output of the parsing?